# Swift: I need to get an index of one of UIVIew collections to know which is tapped

Tags: iphone, arrays, swift, uiview

I need to get an index of one of `UIView` collections to know which is tapped then link to a corresponding array element in the next screen.  Problem seems `sender!` that I have the error message:

> **Could not cast value of type 'UITapGestureRecognizer' (0x107dcdc20) to 'UIView' (0x107dc2578).**

(I used `UIView` to create color tiles. Should I use label or buttons instead of `UIView`?)

```
import UIKit

class ColoringViewController: UIViewController {

var coloringItem: ColoringItem?
var colorListTileArray = [UIView]()

@IBOutlet var colorListTile: [UIView]!   // UIView color tiles 


override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if coloringItem != nil {
        for (var i = 0; i<colorListTile.count; i++) {

            colorListTileArray += [colorListTile[i]]

        }
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showColoringDescriptionSegue" {

        let tappedTile = sender!.self     //<- doesn't work 
        //let tappedTile = sender!.view as! UIView <- doesn't work either :(
        let colorIndex = colorListTileArray.indexOf(tappedTile as! UIView)

        print(colorIndex)
    }
}

@IBAction func showColoringDescription(sender: AnyObject) {

performSegueWithIdentifier("showColoringDescriptionSegue", sender: sender)
}

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not paying attention to how to post. I'll be careful next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  The sender to `showColoringDescription` is the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.  Change the signature to take one of those.  Then pass `sender.view` to `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

In `prepareForSegue`, cast `sender` to `UIView` and use that for the lookup in the `colorListTileArray`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showColoringDescriptionSegue" {

        let tappedTile = sender as! UIView
        let colorIndex = colorListTileArray.indexOf(tappedTile)

        print(colorIndex)
    }
}

@IBAction func showColoringDescription(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showColoringDescriptionSegue", sender: sender.view)
}
```

Comment: My deepest gratitude to Vacawama on Thanksgiving today. I was able to complete this part of coding. (^_^)

Comment: You're welcome!  Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it to turn it green.

Comment: We all had to learn it as well.  It is important to accept answers so people know that your issue is solved and to reward the person providing the answer, of course.  Once you have enough reputation (rep > 15 I think), it is common to up vote the accepted answer as well as any other answers that you found useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to initiate the segue, the recognizer will be the sender in `prepareForSegue`  You can get the associated view using the `view` property:

```
if let recognizer = sender as UITapGestureRecognizer {
    let view = recognizer.view
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still it didn't work. I found using tag to UIView may help this situation?

Comment: Exactly `tag` worked for me as well. Phew... life saver some times.